# How to re-connect to Amazon kubernetes cluster after stopping & starting instances?

Tags: kubernetes

I create a cluster for trying out kubernetes using *cluster/kube-up.sh* in Amazon EC2. Then I stop it to save money when not using it. Next time I start the master & minion instances in amazon, *~/.kube/config has old IP-s for the cluster master as EC2 assigns new public IP to the instances.

Currently I havent found way to provide Elastic IP-s to *cluster/kube-up.sh* so that consistent IP-s between stopping & starting instances would be set in place. Also the certificate in *~/.kube/config* for the old IP so manually changing IP doesn't work either:

`Running: ./cluster/../cluster/aws/../../cluster/../_output/dockerized/bin/darwin/amd64/kubectl get pods --context=aws_kubernetes
Error: Get https://52.24.72.124/api/v1beta1/pods?namespace=default: x509: certificate is valid for 54.149.120.248, not 52.24.72.124`

How to make *kubectl* make queries against the same kubernetes master on a running on different IP after its restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only thing that has changed about your cluster is the IP address of the master, you can manually modify the master location by editing the file `~/.kube/config` (look for the line that says "server" with an IP address).

This use case (pausing/resuming a cluster) isn't something that we commonly test for so you may encounter other issues once your cluster is back up and running. If you do, please [file an issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/new) on the GitHub repository.

Comment: I did try changing the server ip in ```~/.kube/config```. After that running *kubectl* command (e.g. ```./cluster/kubectl.sh get pods``` will result in error written in original question - ```Error: Get https://52.24.72.124/api/v1beta1/pods?namespace=default: x509: certificate is valid for 54.149.120.248, not 52.24.72.124```. Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: The self-signed certificate on the master uses the master's IP as the common name. So you would need to reserve an IP when creating your cluster. This may require some tweaks to the AWS cluster creation scripts.

Comment: Found the place to make tweaks thanks to your comments in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/7828 Will mark as accepted.

Comment: Great! It'd be nice if we could tweak the scripts to use an Elastic-IP by default so that you didn't need to maintain a patch against the repository.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version of Kubernetes you were using but in v1.0.6 you can pass `MASTER_RESERVED_IP` environment variable to `kube-up.sh` to assign a given Elastic IP to Kubernetes Master Node.

You can check all the available options for `kube-up.sh` in [`config-default.sh` file](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.0.6/cluster/aws/config-default.sh) for AWS in Kubernetes repository.